# How to import variables from other files in python ? (In def)

Tags: python

I have this code on test1.py file:

```
def main():
   a = 10
   b = 20
   c = 30
   d = 40
   return a,b,c,d
```

And i want to call those variables in test2.py file, i want to use them separately. This is output i want:

```
Var a = 10
Var b = 20
Var c = 30
Var d = 40
```

These variables have different purpose. What i do now, is that i printing all of variables in test1.py file, which i can't use those variables one by one. The test2.py file:

```
from test1 import *
b = main()

def mainn():
    print(b)
    
mainn()
```

And the output is:

```
(10, 20, 30, 40)
```

I want use those variables separately, how can i do that ?

Comment: Could it be done wit ha `for` loop that iterates through the values?

Comment: Why don't you return it as a list and unpack it

Comment: The *only* thing you get by calling `main()` is that tuple of four numbers.  There are no names associated with the numbers, `a` thru `d` were local variables that have no existence outside of `main()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function returns a Tuple.

You can either select the desired value from the Tuple by its index

```
from test1 import *
b = main()

def mainn():
    print(b[1])
    
mainn()
```

or
assign the variables through a for loop

```
from test1 import *
b = main()

list_of_vars = ['a','b','c','d']
for i, v in enumerate(list_of_vars):
    list_of_vars[i] = b[i]
print(list_of_vars)
```

or unpack the tuple as suggested by Sujay

```
a, b, *other = main()
```

or if you have a limited number of variables then simply

```
a, d, c, f = main()
```

Comment: You can also add ```*b``` which unpacks the tuple

Answer (score 0):

First of all put your `main` into a py-file, e.g. `myvrs.py` in a subfolder (e.g. `module`), like this:

```
| test.py
|-- module
    | __init__.py
    | myvars.py
```

The `__init__.py` is necessary to mark the subfolder as actual python module so you can `import` it from your `test.py`. It can be left empty.

Your `myvars.py` may look exactly like the `test1.py` you described above.

Then you can do

```py
from module.myvars import main

vars = main()

for v in vars:
    print(v)
```